# Which books about Xcode can you recommend?

Tags: xcode

I'm looking for a book about Xcode. I wonder which one might be good for me. I'm looking for a book which goes as deep into Xcode IDE as possible. I want to read everything about it, why they did things the way they did. Like this Groups & Files. It should be as much about Xcode as possible. Almost all Cocoa books talk a little bit about Xcode, but I have like 10 Cocoa books here and basically they all talk about the same little basics. So I still feel "dump" after all and Xcode seems to have a lot more stuff in it than I know about. For example symbolic breakpoints, and other stuff like this. Or the option to split windows. A very good eBook would do the trick as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[XCode 3 Unleashed](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Xcode-3-Unleashed-Fritz-Anderson/dp/0321552636) seems to have more of a focus on the tool itself rather than Cocoa.